# most efficient way to write $f_+$ and $f_-$ using $f$

Tags: function-construction

Consider a two-variable function as follows $$f(a,b)=\frac {T(a,b)+C(a,b)}{V(a,b)} \tag{1}$$ I define a $step$ and then define two new functions using (1) and step as $$f_+(a+step,b)=\frac {T(a+step,b)+C(a+step,b)}{V(a+step,b)} \tag{2}$$ and $$f_-(a-step,b)=\frac {T(a-step,b)+C(a-step,b)}{V(a-step,b)} \tag{3}$$ In fact $f_+$ and $f_-$ are two functions which have been changed by $+step$ and $-step$ for each parameter namely generally a $f_+$ defined as $$f_+(... a_i ...)=f(... a_i+step ...) \tag{4}$$ equations 1-3 were an example. How can I  write a general form for $f_+$ and $f_-$ which adds to or subtracts step from a special variable each time and do this for all variables, do I need a loop? For the sake of simplicity suppose function (1).

**Example:**

I need to step is added to $i$th variable where i is the loop number (in fact I'm running this command inside a outer loop), so if currently loop number is 1, step must be added to $a$ in eq(1) and in the next time when $i$ is 2, step must be added to $b$ in eq(1) and so on. Equation (1) is a special case, but an arbitrary function can have n variable so I need each time  one of them (regarding to loop number) changes.

Comment: The required syntax is almost the same as the traditional math notation: `Clear[f, a, b];

f[a_, b_] = (T[a, b] + cc[a, b])/V[a, b];

fplus[a_, b_] = f[a + step, b]` Why do you think you need a loop?

Comment: because I need to use these $f_+$ and $f_-$ functions into a loop and in an algorithm where these functions are constructed regarding to number of loop, for example if the loop number is 3, I need to construct a $f_+$ function in which step added to its third variable

Comment: The order isn't important, right? Then you don't need loop: `f @@@ Transpose[IdentityMatrix[3] step + {a, b, c}]`

Comment: No, order is important, in fact I don't determine that step must be added to which variable, but the loop number does. So if i be the loop number, step must added to ith variable and the $f_+$ is constructed for that special i

Comment: It would be nice if you present a minimal example.

Comment: Then just use `Part` to extract the desired expression. kglr's answer below is another possible choice, of course. Still, though we sometimes need loop, do remember if you're using loop in _Mathematica_, you're likely to be on the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks but I'm writing a manual algorithm and there is no alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[fpm];
fpm[g_, a__][step_, pos_: 1] :=  Module[{arg = MapAt[# + step &, {a}, {pos}]}, g @@ arg]
```

***Examples:***

```
ClearAll[f,t, v, a, b, c];
f[a_, b_] := (t[a, b] + c[a, b])/v[a, b]

fpm[f, a, b][step]
```

> (c[a + step, b] + t[a + step, b])/v[a + step, b]

```
fpm[f, x, y][-step]
```

> (c[-step + x, y] + t[-step + x, y])/v[-step + x, y]

```
fpm[f, u, t][-step, 2]
```

> (c[u, -step + t] + t[u, -step + t])/v[u, -step + t]

```
h = Total[{##}^2] &;
fpm[h, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6][-step, 3]
```

> x1^2 + x2^2 + (-step + x3)^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 + x6^2

Comment: Thanks, however as I said in the above comment, I need a I need to use these $f_+$ and $f_−$ functions into a loop and in an algorithm where these functions are constructed regarding to number of loop. I think that I can set t in your code equal to my loop number to obtain desire result, right?

Comment: @Wisdom, not sure how you intend to use loop. Maybe you can use the argument  `pos` as the "loop number" to iterate over the positions as in  `Table[fpm[f, a, b][step, i], {i, 2}]` and `Table[fpm[f, a, b][-step, i], {i, 2}]`.

Comment: I added an example. In fact I wanted to construct $f_+$ and $f_-$ functions inside my loop, but seems your idea is good so that I construct a table of all possible functions and call one of them (regarding the loop number) inside my loop each time, right?